# Function that searches a cell for a specific string and returns it in excel vba

Tags: vba, function, find, position, character

I'm wondering if a function is possible that searches for this "1-" in a cell's value and if it can find it, it would copy out the "1-" plus the next 10 characters.

Basicly if "1-" is in a cell, I'd like the function to get that plus the next 10 chars for me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Anything you tried so far? I guess a combination of FIND and other string function could do the trick.

Comment: Did some research and someone already did something very similar, I just had to modify a few things, but in the end this worked:

Answer (score 2):

After some research:

```
Function RetDigits(sIN As String) As String
    Dim lookFor As String, v As String, ary
    Dim i As Long, CH As String
    lookFor = "1-"
    RetDigits = ""
    If InStr(sIN, lookFor) = 0 Then Exit Function
    ary = Split(sIN, lookFor)
    If Len(ary(1)) < 2 Then Exit Function
    For i = 1 To 10
        CH = Mid(ary(1), i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            RetDigits = RetDigits & CH
        End If
    Next i
    RetDigits = "1-" & RetDigits
End Function
```

Comment: Good on you for finding your own answer to your question.